# How to parse/format a string of tuples?

Tags: python, string, list, csv, format

I jus wrote a grade calculating program and am down to the last few lines ... I have this string of tuples :

```
"('Jetson Elroy', '45', '88', '88', '70', 0.7253846153846155, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9385714285714284, 0.6528571428571427, 0.367142857142857), ('Joe Kunzler', '99', '88', '77', '55', 0.7699999999999999, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.8557142857142858, 0.5700000000000001, 0.28428571428571436), ('Harris Jones', '77', '99', '47', '77', 0.7115384615384616, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9642857142857143, 0.6785714285714286, 0.39285714285714285)"
```

I'd like to make it so each student and their scores are printed into my text file line by line, like :

```
'Jetson', '45', '88', '88', '70', 0.7253846153846155, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9385714285714284, 0.6528571428571427, 0.367142857142857

'Joe', '99', '88', '77', '55', 0.7699999999999999, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.8557142857142858, 0.5700000000000001, 0.28428571428571436

'Harris Jones', '77', '99', '47', '77', 0.7115384615384616, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9642857142857143, 0.6785714285714286, 0.39285714285714285
```

I tried to do :

```
m=open('GradeAnalysis.txt', 'r+')
m.write (print i for i in ourlist)
m.close()
```

But I realize you have to have a string if you want to use m.write(). Then I transferred my list into the string of tuples like I have above. Any pythonic suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[`join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) can be a simple solution:

```
m.write('\n'.join(i for i in ourstring))
```

---

*Edit:* Since `ourstring` is not a list of strings but a string, you can use a regular expression to get the strings that represent the tuples

```
import re

ourstring = "('Jetson Elroy', '45', '88', '88', '70', 0.7253846153846155, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9385714285714284, 0.6528571428571427, 0.367142857142857), ('Joe Kunzler', '99', '88', '77', '55', 0.7699999999999999, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.8557142857142858, 0.5700000000000001, 0.28428571428571436), ('Harris Jones', '77', '99', '47', '77', 0.7115384615384616, 'C', 'Not Passible', 0.9642857142857143, 0.6785714285714286, 0.39285714285714285)"
tuples = re.findall(r'\((.+?)\)', ourstring) # (.+?) to perform a non-greedy match - important!
m.write ('\n'.join(t for t in tuples))
```

Comment: This unfortunately prints a line for each character in the string ' \n 'j'\n 'e'\n't'\n

Answer (score 1):

Use either [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) or the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to write your data.

Using `','.join(str(i) for i in ourlist)` creates a comma-separated string to write to the file, but since this is really CSV data, the `csv` module is perhaps better suited.

```
import csv

with open('GradeAnalysis.txt', 'rb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in list_of_sequences:
        out.writerow(row)
```

where `list_of_sequences` is then a list containing other lists or tuples; for example:

```
list_of_sequences = [(1, 2, 3), ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')]
```